# Identify SharePoint 2010 exception

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, exception-handling

I a problem with identifying the origin of the exception in SP 2010 Enterprise.

**Environment:**

- Standalone SP2010
- AAM configured
- Authentication: Claims based.
- SSL enabled.

**Description:**

- New web application created.
- New root site collection created and works correctly (https://www.MySite.com).

**Problem:**

- Any link which is located on the subsite (i.e. MySite\Test) leads to the exception.
- **Set permissions** in MySite\Test shows:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.OpenWeb(String strUrl, Boolean
>   requireExactUrl) +27675215
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.get_RootWeb() +39
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.EnsureFeaturesData() +388
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.get_Hash() +257
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetHashCodeForActiveFeatures(SPWeb
>   spweb) +59    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPRibbon..ctor() +113
>   ASP.MYPORTAL_MASTER_55085331.__BuildControlSPRibbon1() in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\mysite.com80_catalogs\masterpage\MasterPage\Custom.master:67
>   ASP.MYPORTAL_MASTER_55085331.__BuildControlSPSecurityTrimmedControl2()
>   in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\mysite.com80_catalogs\masterpage\MasterPage\Custom.master:62

- **More options** in MySite\Test shows:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.OpenWeb(String strUrl, Boolean
>   requireExactUrl) +27675215
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.get_RootWeb() +39
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.EnsureFeaturesData() +388
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.get_Count() +56
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollectionEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   +58    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPElementProvider.AddElementsFromFeatures(SPFeatureCollection
>   features, CultureInfo culture, SPWeb web, List`1 list) +566

- **Site Settings** in in MySite\Test shows **blank page.**

Reflector shows that **ArgumentNullException** is possible when `strUrl is null`

```
   public SPWeb OpenWeb(string strUrl, bool requireExactUrl)
    {
      if (strUrl == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
      if (this.IsValidWebUrl(strUrl))
        return new SPWeb(this, this.MakeFullUrl(strUrl), requireExactUrl);
      throw new ArgumentException(SPResource.GetString("InvalidUrl", new object[1]
      {
        (object) strUrl
      }));
    }
```

Any ideas where to look further?

Comment: What kind of site template you used? E.g. trying to create MySite Host in STANDALONE SharePoint could generate this error, as the UPSA does not get provisioned!

Comment: @C.Marius It's default team site. But it's good point to start. Thanks

Comment: This sounds daft, but do you have a subsite called Test created? You didn't say so in your steps above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in custom HttpModule and if to be more precise, in accessing SPContext while it was null. Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any exception or it is a blank page?
If it is a blank page try basic authentication for your default website. 
Go to IIS >Click on Sites> Click on your web application or SharePoint Central Administration site ( You will have to follow these steps for all the sharepoint web applications that you create in IIS)> Click on Authentication and enable Basic Authentication> Reset IIS

Now when you access your site it will ask for userid and password. Give proper userid and password.

Comment: Please read the question carefully before posting the answer.